# Align an ionic button at the bottom right of a div

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'd like to place an ionic button at the bottom right of a div. But it doesn't work as I expected. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

My html:

Ionic Blank Starter

```
  <ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="image in images">
      <div class="slider-container">
        <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" style="width:100%;height:auto;margin:0;display:block" >
        <button class="bottom-right button button-positive icon-left ion-home">Home</button>
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
```

The css:

```
  .slider-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
  }

  .bottom-right {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: A demo might help but my guess is that one of the other classes you have applied is affecting the positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why not to do it this way?

```
  <ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="image in images">
      <div class="slider-container">
        <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" style="width:100%;height:auto;margin:0;display:block" >
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <button class="bottom-right button button-positive icon-left ion-home">Home</button>
  </div>
```

...moving the button (and the container `<div>`) out of the slider.

Answer (score 1):

When I needed to put the left and right buttons ("<" and ">") I used class "row" and "col"

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-10">
            <button class="button button-block button-icon button-clear ion-chevron-left" ng-click="slidePrevious()"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="mudaSlide($index)">
                <ion-slide ng-repeat="i in items">
                    <img class="button " ng-src="{{i.imagem}}" style="width: 128px; height: 128px; padding: 0; border: none; background: none;" ng-click="abreExibecaoImagem($index)"></img>                        
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-10">
            <button class="button button-block button-icon button-clear ion-chevron-right" ng-click="slideNext()"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Result

[image]